# Does the value of truth have an approximation threshold?

Tags: logic, ethics, philosophy-of-mind, psychology

In other words, a truth value in a mathematical sense is binary, but human communication is fallible and runs the risk of fallacy, error, and distortion.

The idea of being "close enough" to the truth - even when being sincere - is something I think we can all agree exists so that we do not burden each other with unreasonable expectations of accuracy and precision.

*If for example, someone asks me if the glass is full of water and it is 99% full, I will say - with no burden on my conscience - that it is indeed full.*

**Is it reasonable to conjecture that the human conscience contains a mechanism for assessing truth based on a spectrum of approximations rather than an exact set of criteria that must be met?**

Comment: This is more of a neuroscience and psychology than philosophy question. Neurons fire only when the activation potential reaches a threshold, it is reasonable to assume that such threshold operation filters to the higher cognitive functions as well. It is well established in some areas, pattern recognition for example. You should ask on [Psychology & Neuroscience SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roy Sorensen does think it is reasonable because of the vagueness of the truth predicate in ordinary discourse. He is discussing truth as one of the conditions for knowledge :

> Vagueness in the Truth Condition
>
> Since the objects of knowledge are usually considered to be linguistic
> entities such as sentences or quasi-linguistic entities such as proposi-
> tions, it is natural to expect the objects of knowledge to be vague. Since
> knowledge implies truth, the vagueness of truth-bearers sometimes
> creates unclarity as to whether the truth condition is satisfied.
> For example, Nick asks Nancy 'When will you arrive for lunch?'
> Nancy answers 'Noonish.' Nick watches an accurate clock as he waits
> in order to be sure whether Nancy arrives noonish. Both Nick and
> Nancy understand 'noonish' to mean 'near noon.' If Nick sees Nancy
> arrive at 12:01, then Nick knows Nancy arrived noonish. Likewise, Nick
> knows that Nancy arrived noonish if she arrives at 12:02, 12:03, or
> 12:04. But as we add minutes, uncertainty about noonishness grows.
> Since we cannot specify the last noonish moment, we cannot specify
> the last time at which Nick knows. Our uncertainty as to whether he
> knows that time t is noonish can be traced to the vagueness of 'noon-ish' and thus the vagueness of the object of his belief.

**Reference**

Roy A. Sorensen, 'The Vagueness of Knowledge', Canadian Journal of Philosophy, Vol. 17, No. 4 (Dec., 1987), pp. 767-804 : 768.